# Как восстановить место в справке Vim?

Tags: vim

Допустим, я читал некий топик во встроенной справке Vim. Как вернуться к месту чтения после закрытия и повторного запуска Vim? При этом использовался *Session.vim*. Опция `'sessionoptions'` слово "help" содержит.

Окно со справкой восстанавливается. Проблема в том, что файл справки в этом окне после восстановления становится обычным файлом, в котором забыты теги переходов, да и сами теги по `^]` перестают работать. Выручает копирование тега, `:h <вставка_тега>`. Открывается новое окно справки. При этом предыдущее окно с сохранённой справкой вновь становится окном справки. Вот.

Можно ли сделать это проще?

Vim 7.4 в Linux и Cygwin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это баг. "Починить" теги можно принудительно установив опцию `:h 'buftype'` и др. Например:

> ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/help.vim

```
if &buftype !=# 'help'
    setl buftype=help iskeyword=!-~,^*,^\|,^\",192-255
    setl foldmethod& tabstop&
    setl noarabic nobinary nobuflisted nocursorbind nodiff nofoldenable nolist
    setl nomodifiable nonumber norelativenumber norightleft noscrollbind nospell
endif
```

UPD. Пропатчено Vim 8.2.4007.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Всё сложно. ИМХО, проще перейти к какому-нибудь тегу, `:h ^R^A<Enter>^Wp^Wc`. Но "баг" в Vim-е? Нонсенс! Или я забрёл в нехоженые дали?

Comment: Оказалось, что лечится `:set buftype=help`. Но в `:h 'buftype'` -- "you are not supposed to set this manually". "Будем искать." (c)

Comment: Добавил `setlocal buftype=help` в `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/help.vim`. Вроде заработало, но при закрытии окна файл справки не пропадает из `:ls`.

Comment: @hobo-mts Баги - это не нонсенс, а норма жизни. Buftype-help ставится командой help, но скрипт сессии не умеет использовать help, потому что он сначала создаёт окно, а потом открывает в нем файл командой edit. Help же всегда открывает новое окно сам. А ставить все опции через обычный ftplugin (что я посоветовал выше) - наверное не хочется из-за возможного filetype off...  Короче, я просто сделаю issue, и пусть Bram сам думает, чего с этим делать. А что до нехоженности, да даже я этот глюк видел раньше, просто разбираться лень было.

Comment: @hobo-mts Так я же в ответе перечислил все нужные опции. Эта называется buflisted

Comment: Отображение по `:ls` исправилось при помощи `setlocal nobuflisted`. Виноват, прочитал Ваш комментарий невнимательно. НГ, таки.